# Change Width and Height with Jquery by resolution

Tags: jquery, image, responsive-design

I posted a new question here and i got a answer to how i can remove the image width and height when my screen resolution is lower than 980px.

I got this code:

```
<img width="477" height="299" src="/uploads/2012/01/415.jpg" class="attachment-portfolio2 wp-post-image"/> 

var images;

$(function() {  
    images = $('img.wp-post-image');
    removeSize();
});

$(window).resize(removeResize);

function removeSize()
{
    if($(window).width() < 980 && images.length > 0)
    {
        images.removeAttr('width').removeAttr('height');
    }
}
```

Now, I want change it to "change width jquery comand" and i tryed that:

```
 var images;

    $(function() {  
        images = $('img.wp-post-image');
        removeSize();
    });

    $(window).resize(removeResize);

    function removeSize()
    {
      if ( $(window).width() < 960) {
    $('img.wp-post-image').animate({width:'400px'});
    $('img.wp-post-image').animate({height:'300px'});
}
else {
    $('img.wp-post-image').animate({width:'400px'});
    $('img.wp-post-image').animate({height:'300px'});
}
    }
```

But is not working, what is wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simplify that into a regular function, you'd get :

```
$(function () {
    var images = $('img.wp-post-image');
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        if ($(window).width() < 960) {
            $('img.wp-post-image').animate({ width: '400px' });
            $('img.wp-post-image').animate({ height: '300px' });
        } else {
            $('img.wp-post-image').animate({ width: '400px' });
            $('img.wp-post-image').animate({ height: '300px' });
        }
    });
});
```

that would work just fine, other than the fact that the if / else seems mute, as it does the same thing no matter what,and you're animating the same elements twice at the same time? Are you trying to chain the animations, if so use the callback functionality:

```
$('img.wp-post-image').animate({ width: '400px' }, 500, function() {
      $(this).animate({ height: '300px' }, 500);
});
```